# How to get Client IP with ktor

Tags: java, kotlin, ktor

Hey i tried to get the ip of the client with ktor.

I used the method

```
this.context.request.local.remoteHost
```

(this.context is an Instance of ApplicationCall)

How can i get the real ip an not something like "********.dip0.t-ipconnect.de"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also get a remote host from the request's origin: `call.request.origin.remoteHost`, but it returns the IP address in not every case either.

To get the IP address use the `call.request.origin.remoteAddress` property.

Comment: This issue is marked fixed. They suggest to use `call.request.origin.remoteAddress` instead of `call.request.origin.remoteHost`.